# Largest antichain in partial ordering in OEIS

Tags: co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, posets

OEIS [A109388](https://oeis.org/A109388) $\{a_n\}_{n\ge1}$ is an integer sequence with $a_n=\binom{n}{\lfloor \frac{n}{3} \rfloor}\times 2^{n-\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\rfloor}$, I noticed that OEIS says

> $a_n$ is the **size** of the largest antichain in the partial ordering
> $(0,1,a)^n$ where $0$ and $1$ are less than $a$.

According to the binomial theorem, $(1+2)^n=\sum_{i=0}^{n} \binom{n}{i}\times2^{i}$. Let $b_n(i):=\binom{n}{i}\times2^{i}$ denote the number of elements in $i$-th level in $(0,1,a)^n$.
It is obvious that $b_n(\lfloor\frac{2n-1}{3}\rfloor+1)$ is maximal in $\{b_n(i)\}_{0\leq i \leq n}$, and $b_n(\lfloor\frac{2n-1}{3}\rfloor+1)=\binom{n}{\lfloor \frac{n}{3} \rfloor}\times 2^{n-\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\rfloor}$.

I know every $b_n(i)$ elements in $i$-th level form an antichain in $(0,1,a)^n$. My question is how to prove that $b_n(\lfloor\frac{2n-1}{3}\rfloor+1)=a_n$ is the **size of largest antichain**, i.e. the claim in OEIS.

Comment: You are asking if the poset $(0,1,a)^n$ is "Sperner" (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sperner_property_of_a_partially_ordered_set ). A natural thing is to check if the Sperner property for this poset follows from the fact that it is a product. However, the well-known criterion for Sperner-ness of products established in "Product partial orders with the Sperner property" (https://doi.org/10.1016/0012-365X(80)90118-1) by Proctor, Saks, and Sturtevant does not apply, because the rank sizes of $(0,1,a)$ do not form a symmetric sequence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The poset $(0,1,a)^n$ is isomorphic to the face lattice of an $n$-dimensional cube, with the empty face removed. This lattice can be proved to be Sperner by the same argument Lubell used to prove the Spernicity of the boolean algebra. A reference is the slides [here](https://math.mit.edu/~rstan/transparencies/garsiafest.pdf). Spernicity is also a consequence of the theorem of Greene and Kleitman, On the structure of Sperner $k$-families, *J. Combin. Theory Series A* **20** (1976), 41-68, that for any finite poset $P$, some maximum size antichain is a union of orbits of the automorphism group of $P$. For the face lattice of an $n$-cube, all the elements of a given rank form an orbit.